# Barbarian HP Calculation

Tags: dnd-5e, barbarian, hit-points

I was going through the PHB again recently and read something in the barbarian section that makes me think I've been calculating HP increases wrong when I level up.

I noticed it says:

> Hit Points at Higher Levels: 1d12 (or 7) + Constitution modifier per barbarian level after 1st

Does that mean that, when rolling for HP, I roll 1d12 then add my CON mod multiplied by each level after level 1?

Meaning (At level 6, with +3 CON): HP increase = 1d12 + (3 x 5)

Answer (score 7):

**No**

You add your con once each level up. So at level 9 it would still be 1D12 + 3

Comment: +1: It might also be helpful to point out that the HP addition is recalculated if one's constitution modifier increases.